# sharepoint column formatting json examples with paging

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, column-formatting

I was thinking if I had a list in Modern UI and then use JSON column formatting.
Does it support paging or sorting through the items?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about column formatting or View formatting? In View formatting Pagination is not supported as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Column Formatting**:

If you have formatted your column using JSON formatting, it will **support Sorting and Filtering**.

See below image, "Container Content" column is sorted in descending order and you can use **Filter by** option to filter the rows based on column value.

[image]

**View Formatting**:

SharePoint Online Modern Experience View formatting does **not supports Pagination** as of now.

There is a [SharePoint UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/38419060-pagination-in-modern-list-view-formatting) related to this. If you want Microsoft to implement this functionality then you can vote on the idea.

Comment: Thanks i was after view formatting. Will use the UserVoice

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote and accept it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: Is there paging available for view formatting now?